# Casting a pointer to the wrong type and calling functions on it c++

Tags: c++, pointers, types, void

I'm learning about pointers to objects. I have this code (the comments in main reflect the output for each statement).

Foo stores a void pointer to an object, and checks to see if other pointers to that object are either itself, or reference the same object pointed to by its stored pointer.

When checking objects referenced by the stored pointer, it first casts that pointer to type bar.

In the last few statements, it takes a void pointer to an object of type foo, casts the pointer to object of type bar, and then calls a function on it which only exists in bar. Why does the bar function work when the object is type foo?

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <random>
//#include "sqlite3.h"
//#include "SDL.h"

//#include <cstdlib>

//#include <algorithm>
//#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
//int RunSqlNoCallback(sqlite3 * db, const char * zSql);


class bar
{
    public:
        bar()
        {
            x = 0;
        }

        void checkSelf(void* somePointer)
        {
            if (somePointer == this)
            {
                printf("bar it's me!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("bar It's not me.\n");
            }
        }
        void setx(int y)
        {
            x = y;
        }
        void checkx()
        {
            printf("This bar has x = %i\n",x);
        }

    private:
        int x;
};

class foo
{
    public:
        void checkSelf(void* somePointer)
        {
            if (somePointer == this)
            {
                printf("foo it's me!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("foo It's not me.\n");
            }
        }

        void setsuch(void* someptr)
        {
            somesuch = someptr;
        }

        void checksuch(void* someptr)
        {
            bar* foobar = (bar*) (somesuch);
            foobar->checkSelf(someptr);
        }

        void checksuchx()
        {
            bar *foobar = (bar*) (somesuch);
            foobar->checkx();
        }

    private:
        void* somesuch;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    foo myfoo;
    foo notmyfoo;
    bar mybar;

    mybar.checkx(); //this bar has x = 0
    mybar.setx(5);
    mybar.checkx(); //this bar has x = 5

    foo* myfooptr = &myfoo;
    bar* mybarptr = &mybar;

    myfoo.checkSelf(myfooptr); //foo it's me
    myfooptr = &notmyfoo;
    myfoo.checkSelf(myfooptr); //foo it's not me
    myfoo.checkSelf(mybarptr); //foo it's not me
    myfooptr = &myfoo;
    myfoo.checkSelf(myfooptr); //foo it's me

    myfoo.setsuch(mybarptr);
    myfoo.checksuch(mybarptr); //bar it's me
    myfoo.checksuchx(); //this bar has 5
    mybar.setx(7);
    myfoo.checksuchx(); //this bar has 7
    myfoo.checksuch(myfooptr); //bar it's not me
    myfoo.setsuch(myfooptr);
    //!This next line is the most confusing one. Why does it say "bar" in the output when foo has the same function "checkself" called by "checksuch"?
    myfoo.checksuch(mybarptr); //bar it's not me
    myfoo.checksuch(myfooptr); //bar it's not me
    myfoo.checksuchx(); //this bar has x=8715752
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using the term "work" as a substitute for "undefined behavior can do anything" (even such as appearing to "work").

Comment: *Why does the bar function work when the object is type foo?* -- Because by using a C-style cast, you told the compiler to "shut up, it is a bar", and the compiler (and underlying code) said "ok, I believe you".  What happens after that can be anything.  If you didn't apply those casts, the compiler will tell you by issuing an error that the types are not the same.